# Member object in a class which calls it parential constructor

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor, member

in my .h I've got something like this:

```
class Cbeckhoff_frontendDlg : public CDialogEx
    {
    // construction
    public:
    Cbeckhoff_frontendDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);
    //...
    //this is the member object I want to create
    Modul test;
    };
```

And my .cpp looks like this:

```
Cbeckhoff_frontendDlg::Cbeckhoff_frontendDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialogEx(Cbeckhoff_frontendDlg::IDD, pParent)
    {
    //..
    };
    //and should look like this:
    Cbeckhoff_frontendDlg::Cbeckhoff_frontendDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialogEx(Cbeckhoff_frontendDlg::IDD, pParent),test()
    {
    //..
    };
```

I messed up the former test case I tried to publish here, I'm sorry about that. I guess I don't quite understand what happens there. I assume Cbeckhoff_frontendDlg starts the parential CDialogEx- constructor, but I want to start my own constructor test aswell. Is that possible?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Your second constructor should do what you are trying to do as best I can tell ...

Comment: I only want to create a member object. He's complaining Modul is not defined and that he assumes int, but creating a complete different class without that call of the parential constructor I am able to generate my test object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Modul` has a default constructor and you do not want to use another constructor, the following is already enough:

```
Cbeckhoff_frontendDlg::Cbeckhoff_frontendDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialogEx(Cbeckhoff_frontendDlg::IDD, pParent) {}
```

If you want to use another constructor (e.g., one receiving an integer), you could do:

```
Cbeckhoff_frontendDlg::Cbeckhoff_frontendDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialogEx(Cbeckhoff_frontendDlg::IDD, pParent), test(some_integer) {}
```

**EDIT:** As for the semicolons you should not use a semicolon after a method's body:

```
class Foo {
    Foo() {
        // ...
    } // <- no semicolon

    void bar() {
        // ...
    } // <- no semicolon
}; // <- at the end of a class you need a semicolon
```

Comment: Modul(){};
~Modul() {};
Modul(int ID, Cbeckhoff_frontendDlg* pCbeckhoff,void* pVar,PAmsAddr pAdr){ SetID(ID); plcVar = pVar; pAddr = pAdr;}; I've a default constructor without arguments and one with some Arguments, even if I use the default one it does not work. He complains about a missing semikolon or one too much, but I am pretty sure that is misleading

Comment: @user1534683 You indeed have an extra semicolon at the end of both constructors' definition.

Comment: @user1534683 BTW, if you want to continue receiving answers from the community, you would better start up-voting and accepting useful answers. If you are new to SO, you can have a look at [how the system works](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: Thanks for your introduction. Unfortunately I don't understand where to delete the semicolon..

Comment: @user1534683 Have a look at my updated answer. Hopefully it will be more clear where you need to use a semicolon and where you should not use it.

Comment: Now I cleaned up my whole code the way you adviced me to do, but still this problem is alive. Do you have an idea in which direction I can google?

Comment: If I were you, I would create a minimal test case (see the paragraph "When asking about code" in [this document](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#code)). Then, I would start another post with it. Because the semicolon issue has nothing to do with the issue about the constructor that you are asking here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you code correctly, your Modul class has a constructor which takes an argument of Cbeckhoff_frontendDlg* which has a member of type Modul.
Have you forward declared the Cbeckhoff_frontendDlg class in you Modul.h file?

Edit
Looking at your code again I think you have not seen some of the errors.  You say that the main class is not compiling because modul is undefined.  I would have thought there would also be a compilation error in Modul saying Cbeckhoff_frontendDlg is not defined.  So its possible you aren't compiling the Modul file, **OR** the 'Modul.h' file doesn't have the declaration of the alternative constuctor in.
If I was you I would double check everything you think is being compiled IS being compiled by doing a clean build.

Comment: I never heard about forward declaration before, but it seems to me the right way to go if you have different header files for your classes. In my case class Modul is in the same .h as Cbeckhoff_frontendDlg::Cbeckhoff_frontendDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/) but CDialogEx is in a different .h Is there the problem?

Comment: The name of the files doesn't matter in C++ its just good practice to put classes in files of the same name.
A forward declaration is used where a class (in this case Modul) uses a POINTER to a class (Cbeckhoff_frontendDlg) that uses the first class (Modul).  All you need to do is on the line above "class Modul{" type the statement "class Cbeckhoff_frontendDlg;"  (Do not type the quotes and remember the semi-colon).  This 'tells' the compiler that there is a class called Cbeckhoff_frontendDlg that will be defined somewhere before all the object files are linked.